# Need Help Creating a table?

Tags: mysql

I need help creating a view named `OrderInfo` that will list the customer number, order number, order date, and order amount (the value of `num_ordered * quoted_price`) for each order.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Did you read the page [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?? If not, please do, and then create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Made some formatting improvements.